# ¿Como puedo pasar un evento como parámetro de un método? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Amigos!

Tengo una aplicación Asp.net Webforms en la cual estoy empezando a implementar la librería **SignalR** para hacer algunas cosas en tiempo real con una base de datos SqlServer y SqlDependency.

Tengo este metodo el cual realiza una consulta a la base de datos y devuelve un Json.

```
    public string obtenerDatos(string storedProcedure)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))
        {
            connection.Open();

            //Especifica la consulta que se enviara a la Bd
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                //Ocurre cuando una notificacion es recibida de cualquier comando asociado al objeto dependency
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                //Abre la conexion
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                //Envia la consulta a la bd
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt); ;
    }
```

Esta linea asigna el evento onChange al objeto SqlDependency

```
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
```

Este es el evento que tengo en el codigo:

```
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            ConsultoriosHub.ObtenerDatos();
        }
    }
```

Lo que quiero es pasar como parametro el evento  **dependency_OnChange** en el metodo obtenerDatos con el fin de utilizar esta clase en varias partes pero con diferente implentacion del evento.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que intentas. Que es lo que quieres pasar como parámetro, la variable dependency? Desde donde? Y a donde?

Comment: Quizás no me expliqué bien, lo que quiero es que el evento                       private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)   implemente cualquier clase y cualquier metodo en este caso tiene consultoriosHub.ObtenerDatos() pero si llamo el metodo desde otra clase podria ser  empleadosHub.ObtenerDatos()

Comment: Entonces hablas de una cosa totalmente diferente. En ese caso,lo que yo haria seria definir un interface con el metodo ObtenerDatos ,y que las clases  consultoriosHub y empleadosHub lo implementasen. Pero eso no tiene nada que ver con pasar eventos como parámetros.

Comment: Al principio es lo que tenia pensado pasar el evento dependency_OnChange como un parametro del metodo. Voy a probar con lo que me dices. Gracias

Comment: no entiendo, quieres hacer dinamica la implamentacion del eventos, pero la instancia de "dependency" de donde sale ? cada Hub del lado del servidor tiene su propia implementacion de "dependency" ? porque quizas debas inyectarla usando IoC como ser Unity, Ninject, Autofac, etc entonces dependiendo de que hub se instancia se inyecta un dependency diferente

Comment: el objeto SqlDependency en que contexto lo instancias ? imagino lo haces en la implementacion del hub de signalr del lado del servidor

Comment: Creo que mas o menos va por donde tu dices, la verdad no he usado Ioc nunca... en este momento instancio SqlDependency en la implementación del metodo del lado del server y la idea es que dependiendo del Hub le asigne un evento dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange); diferente

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar creando la interface y segun la clase Hub ejecuta el metodo diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría patrón [Template](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)).

Crea una clase base, por ejemplo: DatosBase y márcala abstracta

```
public abstract class DatosBase
```

En ella coloca el código de `obtenerDatos(string storedProcedure)` tal cual está.

Agrega el método `dependency_OnChange` a la clase base y márcalo `protected` (si no puedes acceder, `public` andaría) y `virtual` (indica que puede sobreescribirse)

```
protected virtual void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
```

Luego haz que todas las clases que quieres que tengan obtenerDatos hereden de DatosBase y sobreescriban el método `dependency_OnChange`:

```
public class Consultorio : DatosBase {
    protected override void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) {
        //Código específico de Consultorio
    }
}
```

Cada vez que llames a `obtenerDatos()` (que está en la clase hija porque lo hereda de la base), la misma va a llamar al `dependency_OnChange` de la hija (porque está sobereescrito)

Comment: Excelente solución! Gracias!